# How to make a single column of buttons using GridBagLayout?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I was curious to see how to implement this. I have been struggling for a while to try getting this to work.

How to make a single column of buttons using `GridBagLayout`?

Comment: You should include your code to the question.

Comment: Yes please let us have a look at what you have tried, so we can help you from that point forward

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out. Apparently, my constructor when I was calling pane.add, I was doing so with only one argument (the button), and I was missing the constraints as the second argument i.e. pane.add(button, c)